# Invisible Vector Causing Issues with Copy Paste Between Illustrator and Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

I got this vector from an EPS online:

[image]

File:  [Weird Badge Vector](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_7h5sk17R61LUowXzc4T1lLMTQ/view?usp=sharing)

It came as a set of two, black and white.  I couldn't separate them so I just deleted all the points of the white one.  When I copy paste between Illustrator and Photoshop this is happens:

[image]

What's going wrong here?  Is there some secret stuff I didn't delete.  How do I fix this?  It makes using the vector really difficult because scaling is all off.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to ungroup them first?

Comment: naturally, did you look at the file I linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in Illustrator.

**If using Illustrator CS6** you will need to release the clipping mask.

Select the object and right click -> Release Clipping Mask. Select clipping mask and delete.

[image: release clipping mask]

For some reason the clipping mask didn't show up in **Illustrator CC**. I am not sure why...

Comment: bless you, that was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you open the file in illustrator and press `CMD + Y` you'll notice the extra stuff masked out in the file.

1. Open file and select the following:

   - Black background (shadow is a drop shadow effect)
   - Google Play mark sections
   - "Get it on"
   - Google Play verbiage
2. Cut `CMD + X`
3. Select All `CMD + A`
4. Delete
5. Paste in Front `CMD + F`
6. Save

This will remove the cruft. You can skip all steps after 1. and place it in PS as a smart object or you can follow all the steps to maintain the eps/ai.